# How to determine a specific vector from a set of vectors in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following two-dimensional vectors Ui for i=1,...,1000

```
import numpy as np
n = 1000
u1 = np.random.uniform(0.5, 4.5, size=n)
u2 = 2 / u1 + np.random.normal(scale=0.09, size=n)
u = np.array([u1,u2])
```

How can I determine what the 500th two-dimensional vector or an arbitrary vector in Ui is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little confusing to call these "two-dimensional vectors", because in NumPy, "dimension" refers to (the length of) the shape of an array. For example, a vector is a one-dimensional array, a matrix is a two-dimensional array, and higher-dimensional arrays are also possible. In particular, `u` is a two-dimensional array with shape `(2, n)`.

IIUC, you want to get the 500th (say) column of `u`, which is a one-dimensional array (vector) with two elements. You can do that with `u[:, 499]`.

More information can be found in the [NumPy documentation on indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html).

Comment: Dear @Arne , Thanks so much for your answer and good explanation. I got it now. I didn't know that before. Yes, I need u[:, 499]. Thank you for the link too.